# error MSB8052: MSVC Toolset Version '14.28.29333' is not compatible with 'v120' Platform Toolset

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2019

I have been facing this issue since long, I am trying to build a project in VS 2019 which has previously built fine in vs 2013. I am facing this error which has no definition anywhere on Microsoft forums.

I have tried doing all the retargeting with the 2019 toolset as well as changing the toolset version to current in the project configuration file with no success at all.

I am not sure why even microsoft forums doesnot have any explanation for this error code (error MSB8052)

Also, the project still shows visual studio 2013 written in brackets in front of the project name. I have changed all the toolset to use the 2019 version but this is not changing.

The error is as follows :  error MSB8052: MSVC Toolset Version '14.28.29333' is not compatible with 'v120' Platform Toolset. Please either change Platform Toolset to v142 or MSVC Toolset Version (VCToolsVersion property) to  the version with the format '12.0*.*'. To use default MSVC Toolset Version for a given Platform Toolset don't set VCToolsVersion property.

I don't know somehow, it is still using the old platform toolset. Can somebody help me with this ?
enter code here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Matrix">
    <MatrixProjectDir>..\..\..</MatrixProjectDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{173A4A3E-C861-4013-9366-08716BF7BCCD}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>LogicNpcUnmanagedSupport</RootNamespace>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseOfMfc>Dynamic</UseOfMfc>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    <CLRSupport>true</CLRSupport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseOfMfc>Dynamic</UseOfMfc>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
    <Import Project="..\..\..\Build\PropertySheets\MatrixReleaseSettings.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
    <Import Project="..\..\..\Build\PropertySheets\MatrixDebugSettings.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_ProjectFileVersion>10.0.40219.1</_ProjectFileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>..\Include;$(ProjectDir)\..\..;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_LIB;_COMPILING_NPC_LIB_;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Lib>
      <OutputFile>$(OutDir)ag$(ProjectName).lib</OutputFile>
      <TargetMachine>MachineX64</TargetMachine>
    </Lib>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>..\Include;$(ProjectDir)\..\..;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_LIB;_COMPILING_NPC_LIB_;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
    </ClCompile>
    <Lib>
      <OutputFile>$(Configuration)\ag$(ProjectName).lib</OutputFile>
      <TargetMachine>MachineX64</TargetMachine>
    </Lib>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="agGuid.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="agLogicNpcBuffer.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="agLogicNpcCallForwarder.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="agLogicNpcClient.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="agLogicNpcDispatcher.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="agLogicNpcException.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="agLogicNpcHeader.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="agLogicNpcServer.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="stdafx.cpp">
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="agArrayWrapper.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="agArrayWrapperComposite.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="agArrayWrapperPrimitive.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="agGuid.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="agLogicNpcBuffer.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="agLogicNpcCallForwarder.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="agLogicNpcClient.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="agLogicNpcContentFlags.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="agLogicNpcDispatcher.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="agLogicNpcException.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="agLogicNpcHeader.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="agLogicNpcServer.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="agLogicNpcServerInfo.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="agLogicNpcTransport.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="stdafx.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="targetver.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>

enter code here -  MatrixDebugSettings.props
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="MatrixBaseSettings.props" />
    <Import Project="MatrixMultiProcessorOptionSetting.props" />
    <Import Project="MatrixDebugBaseSettings.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_ProjectFileVersion>10.0.40219.1</_ProjectFileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

enter code here - Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user.props
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup />
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

Comment: Have you changed the toolset for all build configurations for all the projects?

Comment: Honestly, I'd create projects files anew. Fixing project configuration is pain.

Comment: This does sound like some kind of project corruption. One approach to trying to track it down is to open a Developer Command Prompt and run ``msbuild nameofyour.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /pp:test.out``. Look at ``test.out`` and try to see where ``PlatformToolset`` and/or ``VCToolsVersion`` goes wrong.

Comment: One annoying thing that I am observing is that i have changed and checked v142 everywhere in the project wherever possible, still the project is showing visual studio 2013 in brackets after the project name (for eg LPCUnmanagedSupport*(Visual Studio 2013) ) . and this is not going even after configuration is showing that it is using 2019 toolset. Do you have any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly open vcxproj file, then confirm and modify `Platform Toolset` to `V142`
[image]

If it doesn't work, you could try to delete .vs folder which is next to your sln file.

Comment: Thankyou for writing back, the vcxproj file is already updated with v142, also I tried with deleting the .vs folder but the error stiil remains.

Comment: One annoying thing that I am observing is that i have changed and checked v142 everywhere in the project wherever possible, still the project is showing visual studio 2013 in brackets after the project name (for eg LPCUnmanagedSupport*(Visual Studio 2013) ) . and this is not going even after configuration is showing that it is using 2019 toolset. Do you have any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: @YatharthTomar, could you provide the vcxproj file here?

Comment: project file content has been added in the question itself. Thanks for reaching out again

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I found `$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props` and `..\..\..\Build\PropertySheets\MatrixDebugSettings.props`.  Are they compatible with v142?

Comment: Can you help me by sharing a bit more details about the changes you want in the said prop files, as from my side I have tried changing them manually the tools version to "Current" but the error still remains. Existing (previous) File contents are added in the question itself. Thanks

Comment: I just want to check if the props(targets) file has version limitations. If possible, could you share a sample which could help to reproduce it?